# Excel VBA runtime error 5 using hyperlink function

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm working on a programme where I use hyperlinks to call macros. Therefore I use hyperlink.add function. The function should create a hyperlink on my first spreadsheet with the information of my second spreadsheet.

My problem is that I get a runtime error 5 using following code in my "create hyperlink sub". I don't see where the problem is. Hope you can help me.

```
Sub createhyperlink() 
Dim c1, r1, c2, r2 as Integer
c1=2
r1=2
c2=3
r2=3
    FirstSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstSheet.Cells(c1, r1), _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=Firstsheet.Cells(c1, r1), _
        TextToDisplay:=SecondSheet.Cells(c2, r2)
End Sub
```

Comment: They are defined in my original code. I edited it now.

Comment: Is the empty `Address` intentional? It's required by `Hyperlinks.Add`.

Comment: `Dim c1, r1, c2, r2 as Integer`, only r2 is an integer

Comment: You also probably need `.Text` instead of passing the `Range` to SubAddress and TextToDisplay - those take variants, so they won't be let coerced before the function call.

Comment: why should only r2 be an integer? They are all variables for cell column/row number.

Comment: @Comintern `Adress:=""` means this document.

Comment: @J.schmidt don't ask me, it's by design in VB. You have to specify the type for each variable, even on the same line, else the other are Variant by default.

Comment: Use `Dim c1 as Integer, r1 as Integer, c2 as Integer, r2 as Integer` if you want all `Interger`. And BTW, there is no gain in using `Integer` instead of `Long`.

Comment: @VincentG Thank you, good to know!

Comment: If a variable is for rows DON'T declare it as integer (use Long instead) as you will get overflow errors past 32767 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the .Address and .Value

```
Sub createhyperlink()
    Dim c1 As Long, r1 As Long, c2 As Long, r2 As Long
    c1 = 2
    r1 = 2
    c2 = 3
    r2 = 3
        Firstsheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Firstsheet.Cells(c1, r1), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=Firstsheet.Cells(c1, r1).Address, _
            TextToDisplay:=Secondsheet.Cells(c2, r2).Value
    End Sub
```